# Keycloak direct grant skip login page

Tags: flutter, authentication, single-sign-on, keycloak

i have a mobile app that uses the direct grant to authenticate with keycloak. Inside a webview i want to show my application, that requires a keycloak login. I want to use the direct grant session that is already established and skip the login page for the user. So i have the JWT token with `id_token`, `access_token` and `refresh_token` but need to convert it to a cookie session for the web view. How can i archive that?

Comment: solution was for me to set an HttpOnly cookie with the JWT token in the app and use that for authentication. At the server side i added a custom RequestAuthenticator to authenticate the Token.